# How to speed up writing from Spark dataframe into SQL Server using Pyspark?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

It's taking about 15 minutes to insert a 500MB ndjson file with 100,000 rows into MS SQL Server table. I am running Spark locally on a machine with good specs - 32GB RAM, i9-10885H CPU with 8 cores. I doubt that the machine is being used to its full capabilities. Here is what I am trying.

```
master = "local[16]"

conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName(appName) \
    .set("spark.driver.memory", "16g") \
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g") \
    .set('spark.executor.cores', '5') \
    .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath","./mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre11.jar") \
    .setMaster(master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = sqlContext.sparkSession

def insert_into_ss(start):
    for i in range(start, len(files)):
        item = files[i]
        print(item)

        start = datetime.now()


        spark_df = sqlContext.read.json(upload_dir + '/' +item)
        spark_df = spark_df.select([col(c).cast("string") for c in spark_df.columns])

        print('Casting time', datetime.now() - start)

        spark_df.write.mode("append") \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table) \
        .option("batchsize", 20000) \
        .option("reliabilityLevel", 'NO_DUPLICATES') \
        .option("tableLock", 'true') \
        .option("numPartitions", 16) \
        .option("bulkCopyTimeout", 600000) \
        .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
        .save()
        end = datetime.now()
        print(end-start)
insert_into_ss()
```

Comment: change the master config to `local[4]`. Secondly where is this SQLServer instance located? is it on the same computer or is it on machine that is quite far from where you are. The data is being sent over the wire and what you are looking at is the latency of the network which is not a Spark specific issue

Comment: The SQL server is located far. I think it is a network latency issue as well. Assuming network latency as the primary cause for delay, is there anything else I can do to improve the speed. Would you recommend the Apache Spark connector or any change in the configuration?

Comment: The latency won't be affected by a change of connector. This is a physical hardware issue and not something that Spark connector can resolve